# Hibernate file XML join table with columns not primary key and different name

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I have two tables `PROYECTO` in two different schemas and these tables are relacionada por not primary key columns

```
SHEMA_1.PROYECTO 
varchar COD_PROYECTO

SHEM_2.PROYECTO
varchar CODIGO_PROYECTO
```

in Proyecto.hbm.xml I have

```
<class name="Proyecto" table="PROYECTO" schema="SHEMA_1" optimistic-lock="version">

<join table="PROYECTO"  schema = "SHEMA_2"  optional="true">
     <key property-ref="COD_PROYECTO" unique="true"/>
    <many-to-one name="proyectoContrato"  column="CODIGO_PROYECTO" 
    class="ProyectoContrato" not-null="true"  fetch="select"/>
 </join>
```

And in Proyecto.java

```
private ProyectoContrato proyectoContrato;
```

but when I search projects I get this error:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=THIS_1_.PROYECTO

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Can you please provide the generated SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using:

```
<many-to-one name="proyectoContrato" class="ProyectoContrato" fetch="select" lazy="false" outer-join="true" property-ref="codigoProyecto" insert="false" update="false">
     <column name="COD_PROYECTO"  not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```